# What do we call minimal pairs (words differ by only a single sound) that have similar meanings?

Tags: terminology, semantics, phonology, linguistics, minimal-pairs

What is the term for minimal pairs that have minimal differences in sound *as well as meaning*?

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair):

> In phonology, minimal pairs are pairs of words or phrases in a particular language, spoken or signed, that differ in only one phonological element, such as a phoneme, toneme or chroneme, and **have distinct meanings**.

Here are two examples:

- sit / seat
- affect / effect

After trawling Stack Exchange for similar words, I've also found:

- inept / inapt
- amend / emend

There are possibly many other examples. I'll be glad if anyone can include more examples as well, along with the term for this linguistics phenomenon.

Comment: slit / slot, bong / bang, , to pet / to pat, strike / stroke, strap / strip, bear /  boar (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are ***paronyms*** (see etymology *[here](https://www.etymonline.com/word/paronym)*, if interested). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paronym) defines them as:

> Paronyms are words that are pronounced or written in a similar way but which have different lexical meanings.

It includes examples such as:

> collision and collusion
>  conjuncture and conjecture
>  eclipse and
> ellipse

Quoting R. R. K. Hartmann and Gregory James' ​*Dictionary of Lexicography* (1998), [Thoughtco](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-paronym-1691581) says:

> ***Paronymy***: The relationship between two or more words ***partly identical
> in form and/or meaning***, which may cause confusion in reception or
> production. In the narrow sense the term paronymy refers to
> '***soundalikes***' (cognate near-homophones such as a*ffect/effect* or
> *feminine/feminist*), but in the wider sense it covers any '*lookalike*'
> or '*meanalike*' confusable words.

***Sit - seat*** is definitely a ***minimal pair***. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_pair) explains that

> *minimal pairs* are pairs of words or phrases in a particular language,
> spoken or signed, that ***differ in only one phonological element***, such
> as a *phoneme*, *toneme* or *chroneme*, and have distinct meanings. **They
> are used to demonstrate that two phones are two separate phonemes in
> the language.**

In this case, the minimal pair ***sit-seat*** demonstrates the difference between the phonemes /ɪ/ and /i:/.

Can *sit* and *seat* be also considered paronyms? I guess this should be posted as a different question.

As I mentioned in a comment, sometimes these pairs are intentionally used for humorous or oratorical effect. I found a funny example in Lewis Carol's *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland / Through the Looking-Glass* which is filled with hilarious puns:

> “Why it's simply ***impassible***!
>  Alice: Why, don't you mean ***impossible***?
> Door: No, I do mean ***impassible***. (chuckles) Nothing's ***impossible***!”

Comment: My favorite: *disperse/disburse*

Comment: @JimMack These pairs are quite catchy actually. They are used with amazing effect in literature. A good orator will also know how to make use of them in a convincing way...

Comment: Thanks for your help! Paronym mostly sounds like what I was looking for. It's the similarity but not exact same meaning AND sound that creates the most interference in memorisation.